# Formula/Indirect issue spanning multiple cells in a column

Tags: google-sheets

all!  I'm trying to put a dynamic sheet name into my **Google Sheets** so I don't have to keep editing all these formulas for each sheet I create.  I figured INDIRECT() would work best but now I'm having an issue with the cells being updated in the formula as I pull the formula down to other cells in the column.

I'm currently using:

```
=IF(indirect($J$1&"!$G9")=0,indirect($J$1&"!$C9"),0)
```

This calulates just fine but when I drag the formula down, it doesn't update the $G9 and $C9 cell references, which would force me to go down hundreds of cells and manually edit them.  I'm sure there's a better way to go about doing this, but I'm not sure.

Also, J1 is holding the name of the sheet.  In this case, J1=January by using the following formula:

```
    function sheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

J1 formula is simply `=sheetName()`.  Not sure any of that matters, but just in case...

Comment: Please share a link to the spreadsheet, or a sample version if possible.  Also, look at the ARRAYFORMULA() as a way of not copying the same formula to multiple cells in a row/column.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/miparanormal.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ykKI_Iky-86gEaw0Ic7UuiKy-SC4CEHPe_h73lecco/edit?usp=sharing

This isn't the exact sheet, since that has a lot of sensitive information, but this is a quick one I put together with all the formulas.

Comment: Can you provide View or Edit (preferably) permission to anyone with the link? - I completely understand regarding sensitive data and sample data.  I am often in the same situation.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to update permissions.  Should be set now.

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
=IF(indirect($A$2&"!"&address(row(G3),column(G3)))>0,indirect($A$2&"!"&address(row(H3),column(H3))),0)
```

so that G3 and H3 will change to G4 and H4 etc. as you pull them down.

You might have meant to put > after the first indirect otherwise you always get zero? If not just change it back to =.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By placing the cell reference in quates, it is now alooking inside the quotes for any references.  It is a problem especially noticeable with the query() function.  Likewise, if you insert a row or column in the sheet, the formula will not update the range references in quotes.  So change this to:

```
=IF(indirect($J$1&"!"&cell("address",G9))=0,indirect($J$1&"!"&cell("address",G9)),0)
```

Hopefully this helps!

As for the ARRAYFORMULA() to stop from copying this down the row, you would have to change the formula to maybe a VLOOKUP() function as the INDIRECT() does not allow the use of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this dynamically with the indirect formula and correct usage of address:

`=arrayformula(IF(indirect($J$1&"!"&address(row(),7,4)&":"&address(10,7,4))=0,indirect($J$1&"!"&address(row(),3,4)&":"&address(10,3,4)),0))`

Note that I put a `10` just for example purpose, you should replace that with however many rows you think you will have.

[image]